# Борьба с спамом, алгоритмы выявления

Tags: php, защита

Есть тематический сайт, но на эту тематику есть куча сайтов предоставляющих реферальные системы и из-за этого на данной аудитории очень много спама, как можно выявлять спам в автоматической режиме и с минимальной нагрузкой на сервер и так чтобы не отпугивать людей постоянной каптчёй, подобные сообщения будут модерировать но как сократить список ложных срабатываний анти-спама и сделать список модерируемых комментариев и др минимальным?

Comment: Akismet, например. Ну а user-friendly капчи - совсем другой вопрос.

Comment: Akismet это для Wordpress? Надо будет покопаться в его коде, просто с Wordpress не работаю, я его как то не переношу

Comment: Дело не в вордпрессе, а в технологии.  Плагины-то написать можно к [чему угодно](https://akismet.com/development/api/#use-a-library), у них [открытый API](https://akismet.com/development/api/)

Comment: +1 за Akismet: борьба со спамом автономно, в одно лицо, почти невозможна. И наборот, чем больше разных ресурсов сообща собирают статистику по спаму (например, через Akismet), тем выше качество отлова спама.

Comment: Спам ручной или боты сообщения постят? Если боты, то можно различные мелкие хитрости на форму вешать.

Comment: Akismet спокойно банит сообщения людей без спама ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала сделайте csrf защиту. Поле, содержащее csrf token сделайте динамическим. Это отсечет не целенаправленные спам-атаки ботов. Запросы, сделанные с помощью curl и им подобные отфильтровываются с помощью hidden input, добавленный javasctipt'ом. Можно проверять ip посетителя в спам-базах. Но все это бесполезно, если спамят люди. Для людей можно ограничивать количество сообщений или возможность их отправлять с помощью детекта ссылок или стоп-слов в сообщениях.

Comment: Очень помогло не только для борьбы со спамом, я как то и не задумывался что можно провернуть кросс доменный запрос, таким образом